# How do I resolve a "docker: invalid reference format" error when installing Azure SQL Edge on an M1 Mac?

Tags: docker, azure-sql-edge

I've been trying to install Azure SQL Edge using Docker on my M1 MacBook using [this guide](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-install-sql-server-in-mac-m1-41121e110214) and I'm not able to run the following command:

```
docker run -d — name MySQLServer -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=Y’ -e ‘SA_PASSWORD=your_password123’ -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Because of this error:

> docker: invalid reference format

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue and used the same [documentation](https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-install-sql-server-in-mac-m1-41121e110214). I was able to fix it by typing the command instead of copy pasting

```bash
docker run -d --name MySQLServer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=yourpassword' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Answer (score -1):

If you copy the command directly from the blog post you linked, it won't work because some of the symbols have been replaced.

Instead of an em-dash (`—`) in front of the `name` parameter, you need to use two hyphens (`--`) and instead of fancy single quotes (`‘`) around the `ACCEPT_EULA` and `SA_PASSWORD` environment variables, you need to use apostrophes (`'`).

Here's a version with the replacements made:

```
docker run -d --name MySQLServer -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=your_password123' -p 1433:1433 mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Comment: This is still not working with m1 processor. Can you please give the logs of run
```